# Binding multifunctional WPF DataGrid

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, wpfdatagrid

How would you go about binding a WPF datagrid that needs to display data from many different datasources with varying number of columns with different column headers and types?

What I'm currently doing is creating a custom `List<DataGridColumn>()` list of datagrid columns in my ViewModel for each different collection of records to be displayed in this DataGrid.

I Loop over this List to set the DataGrid columns:

```
foreach (DataGridColumn dgc in dgcSample)
{
  dgc.HeaderStyle = hStyle;
  dgMyDataGrid.Columns.Add(dgc);
}
```

Finally, I use the ItemsSource to set the source of items:

```
dgMyDataGrid.ItemsSource = SomeCollection;
```

This works but it is not binding and it breaks the MVVM guideline that ViewModel should be agnostic to specific UI elements since it now has to deal with the `DataGrid` and host a collection of `DataGridColumn` objects...

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you considered using the datagrid derived class shown in http://www.codeproject.com/KB/grid/MultiColumnSetDataGrid.aspx

This will allow you view to define multiple column sets in your view and switch between them.

Answer (score 2):

I think you have to bind your `DataGrid` with one datasource, but your task is just creating this datasource.

I'll create a sample for creating a DataSource from different entities using [LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa904594.aspx)..

Assuming you have two different entities: Entity1 and Entity2, and each one has common ID:

```
class Entity1
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string E1Column { get; set; }
}

class Entity2
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string E2Column { get; set; }
}
```

You can create the DataSource using [Join](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397941.aspx) in LINQ like the following:

```
List<Entity1> e1List = new List<Entity1>();
e1List.Add(new Entity1() { ID = 1, E1Column = "E1 a" });
e1List.Add(new Entity1() { ID = 2, E1Column = "E1 b" });

List<Entity2> e2List = new List<Entity2>();
e2List.Add(new Entity2() { ID = 1, E2Column = "E2 a" });
e2List.Add(new Entity2() { ID = 2, E2Column = "E2 b" });

var query = from e1 in e1List
            join e2 in e2List on e1.ID equals e2.ID
            select new { ID = e1.ID, E1Column = e1.E1Column, E2Column = e2.E2Column };

// Bind the DataGrid
dataGrid1.ItemsSource = query.ToList();
```

Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

IMO the right way of doing this is to encapsulate all the data sources into a single object, that is similar to your custom `List<DataGridColumn>()`. Call this `MultifunctionalSource`.

This new object will contain a the list of the columns, probably with methods to add new sources and aggregate them. Possibly when adding a new source you could automatically manage the list of columns.

`MultifunctionalSource` is responsible for providing a bindable datasource.

The model will provide objects of type `MultifunctionalSource` to the View.

Within the view you should have a new control derived from datagrid that will understand how to display objects of type `MultifunctionalSource`. This new control will probably be quite simple in the first instance as it can simply setup its columns based on the binding.

`MultifunctionalSource` should probably return a list of columns that it thinks are relevant for display. It should also be able to return a complete list of columns to enable the UI to decide which columns are relevant based on other criteria; thus keeping the boundaries.