# WPF - How to reuse listbox for display of different lists of objects?

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding, binding

I have a ListBox which I am using to display the results of various searches.  Those searches can occur on many different types of objects and I'm having a bit of trouble getting it to work in all circumstances.

Most of the time I can just set ListBox.ItemSource = List and it's works fine if I also set the DisplayMemberPath and the SelectedValuePath.  I run into trouble when the string I'd like to display for a given object is actually a method or a combination of properties.

Can someone please point me in the correct direction for solving this problem?

Thanks,
Sonny

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There a couple of options I can think of.

1. Create a datatemplate for each object in the listbox
2. Create a wrapper class and bind your listbox to a list of those wrapper classes.  It would take a little work to create a constructor (or other method) for every possible search result class.

Comment: #1 did the trick.  I set the different templates in the code behind with something like this: `this.lstSearchResults.ItemTemplate = (DataTemplate)this.FindResource("clientListing");` where "clientListing" is the name of the template I wanted to use.  :)

Comment: If you set the TargetType in your datatemplate and get rid of the key, I don't think you even have to set the itemtemplate.. it will find it automatically.

Comment: Rather than setting the template in code-behind, why not create a DataTemplateSelector?

Answer (score 0):

Funny, I just asked a very similar [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3990680/binding-multifunctional-wpf-datagrid) about the `DataGrid`.

What you could do is create a custom collection of `ListBoxItem` objects for every type of search object and add those items to the `ListBox` at runtime.

```
List<ListBoxItem> lbiTest = GetListBoxItems();
foreach (ListBoxItem lbi in lbiTest)
{  
  lbMyListBox.Items.Add(lbi);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't adding the items into my ListBox manually defeat the purpose of DataBinding?

Comment: That was my question exactly... it is also going against the MVVM guidelines by making your ViewModel aware of specific UI controls... hopefully someone could share some good insight...